# How to Preserve Sheet Formats and Translate? ( Google Apps Script, google sheet )

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

How can i Preserve Sheet Formats and Translate?
I don't want to use the translation latency(1000) or translate cell by cell. it was worked well but I have a large amount of text I want to translate.

[image]
I used the following code:

```
var range1 = sheet1.getRange("A:A");
text1 = range1.getValues();
translatedtext = LanguageApp.translate(text1, 'ko', 'en');
```

This is the starting language. from log. after getValues from sheet.
If I 'setValue' this into the sheet as it is, it will be written in each cell as it is.

```
[안녕하세요], [사과], [], [바나나]
```

This is how it is translated.
Line breaks are gone and replaced with commas, when pasting them into a sheet, it puts all the text in one cell.

```
hello, apple,, banana
```

Comment: Although unfortunately, I cannot know your actual Spreadsheet, I proposed 2 scripts. Could you please confirm it? If those were not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to translate the cell values of the sheet by reducing the process cost.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

In this pattern, the cell values are translated after the retrieved values were converted to the string. By this flow, `LanguageApp.translate` is used by one call.

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set your sheet name.
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow())
var values = JSON.parse(LanguageApp.translate(JSON.stringify(range.getValues()), 'ko', 'en'));
range.offset(0, 1).setValues(values);
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from column "A", and the values are translated, and then, the translated values are put into column "B".

#### Modified script 2:

In this pattern, the cell values are retrieved as the CSV data, and translated it. And then, the translated values are parsed and put into the cells. By this flow, `LanguageApp.translate` is used by one call.

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set your sheet name.
var url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?exportFormat=csv&id=${ss.getId()}&gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}`;
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
var csv = res.getContentText();
var translated = LanguageApp.translate(csv, 'ko', 'en');
var ar = Utilities.parseCsv(translated).map(([a]) => [a]);
sheet.getRange(1, 2, ar.length).setValues(ar);
// DriveApp.getFiles(); // This comment line is used for automatically detecting the scope of Drive API.
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from column "A", and the values are translated, and then, the translated values are put into column "B".
- If an error related to the scopes occurs, please include the scope of Drive API.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: I used the second script.
Google Translate caused an error because it limited the number of characters up to 5000 characters at a time, but it seems that this can be solved by finding out the number of characters to be translated in the sheet, dividing it, and creating a few iteration scripts!

Comment: and first script's `JSON.parse(LanguageApp.translate(JSON.stringify(range.getValues()), 'ko', 'en'));` occur `SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON` by characters 'w', '<', '\' ... and others.

Comment: @icecream sugar black Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.